# How to determine convergence or divergence. $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} n^{\alpha}\cdot \ln^{\beta}(n/(n-1)) $

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

How to determine convergence or divergence of this series depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?  $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} n^{\alpha}\cdot \ln^{\beta}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right) \qquad(1)$$

When $\alpha=\beta=0$, $\ \ \ (1) = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}1$ which is divergent.

I've tried using the ratio test. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} =\lim_{n \to \infty} {\left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^\alpha}\left( \frac{\ln \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n-1} \right) }} \right)^\beta = 1.$$
for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0 \}$.

To calculate the limit of logarithms  I have used L'Hôpital's rule. 
But this is useless because the ratio is $1$. Can you give some hint?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that as $n\to +\infty$,
$$0<\ln\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\sim\frac{1}{n}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: In case the OP is not familiar with the use of $\sim$: this is the [Landau asymptotic notation for equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations).

Comment: @ClementC Thanks for pointing out.